# store json object from ajax to javascript 2d array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm sending an ajax request from js to php.

In the php code I create some 2-D array like this:

```
$arr = array();
for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++){
    $array[$i][0] = rand(0,100000);
    $array[$i][1] = rand(0,100000);
    $array[$i][2] = rand(0,100000);
}

header("Content-Type: application/json", true);

echo json_encode($CalcTable);

exit;
```

On the js file, I get the `data` parameter (the parameter that returned from the ajax done function) like an object that contains 100 arrays inside.

I want to convert this returned object to a js array that contains all the 100 arrays inside it (and all each array contains the 3 arrays with the random values).

Thanks!

Comment: it's json. it already **IS** javascript. assuming you're doing this via jquery, and a `$.getJSON()` call, then it's already been decoded into a native js array and you just start using it.

Comment: What have you tried? What challenges are you facing? We're happy to help, but we're not going to write the program for you.

Comment: I dont want you to write the program for me...............................
I just want you to help me solve my problem...
As I wrote I get back an object that contains 100 arrays. I want to store this object inside other array. On chrome "watch" area I stored it on the array and saw it like an object and not like an ragular array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are are starting your array at index `1` instead of `0`.  When encoding this, PHP "converts" into an object, because arrays *must* start at `0`.

To fix, this you need to create an array of your 3 values, then push it into the main array.

```
for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++){
    $array[] = array(rand(0,100000), rand(0,100000), rand(0,100000));
}
```